# Query subrequest; convert procedural

Tags: 7, database

I've got this request.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `node` WHERE uid = 1 AND type = 'article' )
FROM  `comment` 
WHERE uid = 1
```

Currently, I'm executing this with 2 different `EntityFieldQuery` objects.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
          ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
          ->propertyCondition('type', 'article')
          ->propertyCondition('uid', 1)
          ->count()
          ->execute();
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
          ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment')
          ->propertyCondition('uid', 1)
          ->count()
          ->execute();
```

How can I make only 1 request (`EntityFieldQuery`, `db_select()`, or `db_query()`)?

Comment: How are you doing that with an EntityQuery? EntityQuery doesn't take SQL arguments. You haven't given enough information here.

Comment: @Jaypan check my Edit

Comment: What do you mean by _I'm executing this with 2 different EntityQuery._? What is  different between the first execution and the other one?

Comment: @kiamlaluno the first return all nodes created by uid, and the second return all comments by uid